# mouse over button event in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mouseevent

I have a web app that has 3 buttons on it, under it there is a textbox with no text on it, I would like to create an event that fills the textbox when a user hovers his mouse over the button, can someone please point me in the right direction

Thank

Comment: Don't need ASP.NET or C# to do this.  Javascript would take care of everything.  <img onmouseover="document.getElementByID("#myText").value='fdafdsa'> for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="button" onmouseover="javascript:document.getElementById('textbox').value='Hello'" />
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use jQuery to do this

```
<input type="button" onmouseover="fillText()" />
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox" />
```

And the JavaScript/jQuery

```
function fillText() {
   $("#textBox").val = "Your Text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

server have no more info about client side, but you could do that with AJAX updatepanel. use a java function to write mouse position in hidden text. then read hidden text in server side with triggers (in condition update mode) or timer (in always update mode).